# Is it a good idea to use monospace font in html forms?

Tags: css, forms, monospace

The *textarea* is in html styled as `font-family: monospace;` If I wanna have consistent appearance I apply this also for my *text inputs*. 
For me it looks like good. But the question if it's *"correct"*?
Cause on the *web* it's usual to use for presentation (= what is on the screen style) some *sans-serif* font. 
This *monospace* actualy have these little ends of letter similar to *serif*, which is better for printing (=>beter on paper). 

 *So back to my question:* **Is the use *monospace* in this case in accordance with the customs of the Web or is it a mistake? I mean something that is good in this case to use?**

Comment: It really comes down to opinion. I personally like monospace fonts such as Courier New - I use it on my website(s), and my text editor. It has great support too, as basically every computer has it installed, no need for a fallback font, as it pretty much is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Good" is whatever you want it to be. Think about two things:

1. your user. 
   Does your choice of font make their life easier (more readable etc)?
2. your 'brand': do you want this to be your "look"?

There is no right or wrong answer - except "it depends".

Comment: In the first place I think it has cool look (only this inputs) rest of the form like labels and rest of the text is sans-serif, it has good contrast, but the mono is also quite thin so its not too distractive. BUT how common is it? Would you be comfortable if you should use it on your website?

Comment: There are many monospaced fonts - pick one that is not too thin. If the font size is not too small it is OK - make sure there is enough contrast between font and background. Know that white letters on dark background are easier to read… but rarely used in websites. That "looks like it was printed on paper" look - which was called WYSIWYG in the early '90s - is not actually great for the eye. Seeing a little bit of black in a sea of white is harder than the opposite. You can see a star at night. Have you ever seen a black hole during the day? That's my point.

Comment: A couple of useful links: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/11/comparing-font-legibility.html and http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts